# How to concatenate strings in numpy (to create percentages)?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix created by the following code:

```
import numpy as np
table_vals = np.random.randn(4,4).round(4) * 100
```

and I've tried to convert numbers into percentages like this:

```
>>> table_vals.astype(np.string_) + '%'
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')
```

and like this:

```
>>> np.str(table_vals) + '%'
"[[ 137.08 120.31 -55.73 43.6 ]\n [ -94.35 -105.27 -23.31 59.16]\n [-132.9 12.04 -36.69 106.52]\n [ 126.11 -91.38 -29.16 -138.01]]%"
```

but all of them failed. So what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the formatting as:

```
[["%.2f%%" % number for number in row] for row in table_vals]
```

If you want it as a numpy array, then wrap it in `np.array` method so it becomes:

```
np.array([["%.2f%%" % number for number in row] for row in table_vals])
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`np.char` module](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.char.html) can help here:

```
np.char.add(table_vals.astype(np.bytes_), b'%')
```

Using an object array also works well:

```
np.array("%.2f%%") % table_vals.astype(np.object_)
```